config file not found in my python project folder
we have the following project structure:
> /project_folder
>      ...
>      config.py
>      /files
>        my_file.py
>        ....

and my_file.py starts like this:
import sys

from pathlib import Path

sys.path.append(
    str(Path(__file__).parents[1])
)
import config

I receive the following error: AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'PATH_CONF'
I checked which config file is sued and it turned out that the path of the used file is
.../fast-api-solution-Nlz8SRuo-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/config/init.py
So for some reason it is not using my project_folders config.py file.
If I now change the file name to config_pcf.py everything works fine.
For my colleague wo uses the same repo it is working without getting any error.
Any idea why the "sys.path.append.." is not working in my case?

You have at some point installed a config package globally (probably this one: https://pypi.org/project/config/ - not the best name for a library). This takes precedence over any local modules or packages withthe same name. Either rename your config.py or remove the globally installed one with pip. As an aside, I wouldn't recommend installing pip modules globally unless you really know what you're doing, create project specific virtual environments instead and install any required libraries there to keep the project dependencies independent of one another.

Ah on second thought, based on the path it seems like you are already using a virtual environment. The rest of the comment still stands though - you have a naming conflict with a library package, rename your file or remove that package from your environment.

Since python by default only search in the directory that the entry point script is running, so you will have to add this to the sys.path
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../')

import config

Hope i've helped
This question was already answered before:
Importing files from different folder

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
